# URL Routing Application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, url-routing

In a Ruby on Rails application I want to have this routing:

- for URL *www.example.com/reports* go to controller `documents` and action `reports`
- for URL *www.example.com/charts* go to controller `documents` and action `charts`

In the routes.rb file I currently have:

```
scope controller: :documents do
  get 'reports' => :reports
  get 'charts'  => :charts
end
```

The code works as expected, but is there a way so I keep the code *dry* and don't repeat the action names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following. (I assume you already have a resourceful route for your documents right?)

```
resources :documents do
  collection do 
    get 'reports'
    get 'charts'
  end
end
```

To take advantage of the nested routing provided by rails ([see the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes))

Which will generate the following urls:

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                    Controller#Action
reports_documents GET    /documents/reports(.:format)                                                   documents#reports
 charts_documents GET    /documents/charts(.:format)                                                    documents#charts
```

If you don't have any resourceful route, you have to declare it like you already did. The only thing to do would be iterating over an array like this:

```
scope controller: :documents do
  %w(reports charts).each do |action|
    get action
  end
end
```

But IMO this hurts the readability of the code, and is only necessary when dealing with a lot of routes.

Comment: Code dumps ('try this:') are not allowed as answers here. Please add what this does and why it is better than OPs solution.

Comment: @Coal_ sorry, first time I do code review and not answering on stackoverflow.

Comment: Your example works. You're right about readability, but I was just wondering how to do it, as I tried but I was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use non-restful actions, you will have to define all of the custom actions.